# Why isn't this working - using :not() with an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seem to have another issue that I am not conquering. Real simple premise.
I have a mousedown event, and basically IF one particular element on the page is clicked, I want nothing to happen, else I want hide() some div.

```
    $(function(){
        $("document :not(#_ignorelement)").mousedown(function(event){
                if($('#_hidethiselement').length){
                    $('#_hidethiselement').hide();
                }
        })
     })
```

That is not working at all. I also tried the following:

```
    $(document).not($("#_ignorelement")).mousedown(function(event){

    $(document).not("_ignorelement").mousedown(function(event){
```

IF I can solve that, curious how I would actually have ":not" encompass the parent div, like so:

```
$().not("_ignoreelement").parent().closest('div').mousedown(function
```

Because the element "_ignorelement" is an anchor tag that is in a div. Wonder how I can use the parent div perhaps, instead of the anchor tag.

Anyways, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `mousedown` and not `click`?

Comment: I think you need `html` or `body` instead of `document` in your first selector

Comment: i am using mousedown because there are some items/elements on the page which have their clicks caught before they can propagate up the DOM, so I need another method to know if a click has happened, ie. mousedown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document` isn't a node that you can select. Try this instead:

```
$(function(){
    $("body :not(#_ignorelement)").mousedown(function(event){
        if($('#_hidethiselement').length){
            $('#_hidethiselement').hide();
        }
        return false;
    })
 });
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9an9U/)

Comment: Thanks for the catch @VisioN. I added a `return false` statement to prevent that.

Comment: You also need to cancel bubbling. Otherwise all parent elements will also receive a `mouseup` event.

Comment: When you return false from a jQuery event handler, I believe the default action and event propagation are both stopped. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var ignoreNode = jQuery('#_ignorelement')[0];

jQuery(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (ignoreNode === e.target || jQuery.contains(ignoreNode, e.target)) {
    // If the target is, or is inside the ignoreNode, don't
    // do anything.
    return;
  }

  // Do your hiding handling here 
});
```

Note that it really is a good idea to cache your jQuery objects so that you're not running selector queries on every event!

Comment: thanks a bunch in regards to the reminder to cache them. That slipped my mind. :_)